# Change default location of LocalDb

Tags: entity-framework, localdb

I am programming with EF5-code first and want to use LocalDb. How can I change the default location of LocalDb database file? Default location is %USERPROFILE% directory according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx

Previously I was using SqlCe DbConnectionFactory which accepts a parameter for database path/name. If I use AttachDbFileName parameter then it raises an exception if database doesn't exist (it's supposed to create it!).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I specify the filename for a localdb database in entity framework 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989371/can-i-specify-the-filename-for-a-localdb-database-in-entity-framework-5)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I got this working thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989371/can-i-specify-the-filename-for-a-localdb-database-in-entity-framework-5). The answer is simple. Basically I added

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DataModel.Context" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\database.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to the configuration section of app.config and it magically replaced the "database" with my actuall database (DbContext) name. EF code first also works perfectly to create the database if it doesn't exist.