# Cannot connect to SQL LocalDB on Build Server

Tags: localdb, sql-server-2012-localdb

My tests were locally working against Local DB using the `(localdb)\v11.0` instance when a teammate mentioned we're all on version 12 now and some people on the team might not have v11.

The build server was working fine.

So I changed the connection string to `(localdb)\ProjectsV12` and checked all LocalDB versions were on our TeamCity server, they are.

The team is all fine but the build server fails some tests with:

> Test(s) failed. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related
>   or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50
>   - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist. )

It all looks to be setup properly, I can't work out why its failing.

(QA, I know the reason already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because `(localdb)\ProjectsV12` is an instance that's created by SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) in Visual Studio and does not exist on the build server.

Use `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` in your connection strings instead, that's the proper one for 2014.

Credit to @ErikEJ in:

[LocalDB SQL Server 2014 Express creates 2 instances (localdb)\ProjectsV12 & (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197359/localdb-sql-server-2014-express-creates-2-instances-localdb-projectsv12-loc)