# Why do I have these connections?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, localdb

Why do I have these connections ??

What is that ProjectsV13 thing and how is it different from the one above it ??

Why upper connection is Pascal Case and that one below it is lower case?

Why the upper one says SQL Server 13.0.4001 and the bottom one is SQL Server 13.0.4001.0?

What's the difference? Two different SQL Servers? I didn't install none of them. Where did they come from and why there are two of them with different names?

Whats the difference between MSSQLLocalDB and ProjectsV13? Why not Project, why is it Projects, with "S"?

[image]

Comment: EF thing? Try deleting them and see what happens..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LocalDB SQL Server 2014 Express creates 2 instances (localdb)\ProjectsV12 & (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197359/localdb-sql-server-2014-express-creates-2-instances-localdb-projectsv12-loc)