# "MSSQLLocalDb" automatic instance of SQL Server 2014 or 2016?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I have just installed VS2019 with "SQL Server Data Tools" which automatically installed two instances of LocalDb on my machine (both with version 2016 SP1).

1. **MSSQLLocalDb** (automatic instance)
2. **ProjectsV13** (named instance I think)

After that, I separately downloaded and installed SQL Server 2014 LocalDb with an expectation that I'll automatically get a third instance with version 2014. But unfortunately, I didn't get it. [After searching on Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197359/localdb-sql-server-2014-express-creates-2-instances-localdb-projectsv12-loc) I came to know that SQL Sever LocalDb 2016 and 2014 have same name of automatic instance (i.e. MSSQLLocalDb) and we have to use the LocalDb Command Line utility to manage that which version of SQL Server will own the MSSQLLocalDb.

Can somebody help me to have separate names for the automatic instances of both versions (2016 and 2014) so that both automatic instances can coexist on same machine?

I know I can create a named instance of either version which can have the name of my choice but I don't want to do that. I just want automatic instances.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. When you just access it by name, there's no way for it to know which one you want.

A better question though, is why do it at all? The 2016 instance can do whatever the 2014 one does. And if you really want to restrict what it can do, just use the 2016 instance for both but set the database compatibility level to the 2014 level when that's all you want.

Comment: _A better question though, is why do it at all? The 2016 instance can do whatever the 2014 one does._ 
Because some of my clients use SQL Server 2014 and we have exchange backups of DBs back and forth. I have tried to downgrade the compatibility level and generated the DB scripts but that didn't work. I don't know why. So its better to stay with the verion which my clients are using.