# LocalDB is unresponsive in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, localdb

Applications are unable to connect to my LocalDB database, when I inspect it in VS 2017, I get a spinny wheel for some time when I try to expand the node, then this:

[image]

What does it mean and how can I fix it - I am not seeing any errors just the grey icon?

Comment: This is by design - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197359/localdb-sql-server-2014-express-creates-2-instances-localdb-projectsv12-loc/27201328#27201328

Comment: @ErikEJ I don't think it's by design I've been able to deploy and view databases there for several months then it just stopped working :)

Comment: You should ot add your own database to that instance, use (localdb)\mssqllocaldb for that.